# Returning an array of objects only if an object in that array exists in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I have the following two Arrays

```js
const salesDates = ['2021/06/30','2021/07/01','2021/07/02','2021/07/03','2021/07/04','2021/07/05','2021/07/06','2021/07/07']
```

and

```
const jsonSalesData = [
{date: '2021/07/01', company: 'ABC', sales: '32460'},
{date: '2021/07/02', company: 'ABC', sales: '28165'},
{date: '2021/07/03', company: 'ABC', sales: '31546'},
{date: '2021/07/04', company: 'ABC', sales: '12654'},
{date: '2021/07/05', company: 'ABC', sales: '26457'},
{date: '2021/07/06', company: 'ABC', sales: '20351'},
{date: '2021/07/07', company: 'ABC', sales: '56404'},
{date: '2021/07/01', company: 'DEF', sales: '32460'},
{date: '2021/07/02', company: 'DEF', sales: '28165'},
{date: '2021/07/03', company: 'DEF', sales: '31546'},
{date: '2021/07/04', company: 'DEF', sales: '12654'},
{date: '2021/07/05', company: 'DEF', sales: '26457'},
{date: '2021/07/06', company: 'DEF', sales: '20351'},
{date: '2021/07/07', company: 'DEF', sales: '56404'},
]
```

What I need to do is only extract the `sales` in the `jsonSalesData` array for each `company` *ONLY* if the `date` matches the `salesDates` list.

Additionally, I need to set the `sales` to equal to 0 if it isn't found in that array.

For example,
I'd like to have `{date: '2021/07/06', company: 'ABC', sales: '20351'}` returned, but *not*

`{date: '2021/07/01', company: 'ABC', sales: '32460'}` because `2021/07/01` does not exist in `salesDates`

I've tried nesting for loops and such but cannot figure this out.

Comment: thanks @HereticMonkey it looks like you were the first to find this. I failed to mention in my original post that if the date doesn't match in the salesDates array, I need to set the `sales` to 0.

Comment: Sounds like a different question, but you'd use similar logic; `var salesData = jsonSalesData.map(datum => salesDates.includes(datum.date) ? datum : { ...datum, sales: '0' });`

Comment: BTW, it's not good manners to change a question once it's been answered.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
jsonSalesData.map(data => {
    (!salesDates.includes(data.date))&&(data.sales = '0')
    return data;
})
```

Comment: Answers which explain code rather than simply plopping the code down with "try this" are more often upvoted that those that do. Also, please try to use professional English, not txtspk like "plz". Finally, if you see a comment that starts with "Does this answer your question?" and a link to another question, take a moment to follow that link and see if any of the answers there answer this question. If so, you do not need to answer this question -- it's already been answered.

Comment: HI @camper thanks. I added an if statement to account for each company -- is there a way I can set the sales to 0 if the date doesn't match?

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Joey I've updated my code. Hope you kindly check.

Comment: @camper -- this set all the sales to 0

Answer (score -1):

Loop through `salesDates` and inside the loop loop through `jsonSalesData`. Inside the loop, check whether the `date` property is equal to the current `salesDates` item, and if so, add to the array.

Store whether a sales item with the same date was found in a variable and set this to true if one is found. If one is not found, we construct a new JSON with the `sales` property set to `0`, and add it to the array

```js
const salesDates = ['2021/07/04', '2021/07/05', '2021/07/05', '2021/07/06', '2021/07/07']

const jsonSalesData=[{date:"2021/07/01",company:"ABC",sales:"32460"},{date:"2021/07/02",company:"ABC",sales:"28165"},{date:"2021/07/03",company:"ABC",sales:"31546"},{date:"2021/07/04",company:"ABC",sales:"12654"},{date:"2021/07/05",company:"ABC",sales:"26457"},{date:"2021/07/06",company:"ABC",sales:"20351"},{date:"2021/07/07",company:"ABC",sales:"56404"},{date:"2021/07/01",company:"DEF",sales:"32460"},{date:"2021/07/02",company:"DEF",sales:"28165"},{date:"2021/07/03",company:"DEF",sales:"31546"},{date:"2021/07/04",company:"DEF",sales:"12654"},{date:"2021/07/05",company:"DEF",sales:"26457"},{date:"2021/07/06",company:"DEF",sales:"20351"},{date:"2021/07/07",company:"DEF",sales:"56404"}];

const n = [];
salesDates.forEach((e)=>{
  var found = false;
  jsonSalesData.forEach(f => f.date == e? n.push(f) : '');
  if(!found) n.push({date: e, company:'ABC', sales:0})
})

console.log(n);
```

Comment: The OP has admitted this was a duplicate.

Comment: hi @spectric -- I ran that code but it's returning objects with dates that do not exist in the salesDates array e.g. ({
    "date": "2021/07/02",
    "company": "ABC",
    "sales": "28165"
  },)

Comment: thanks @spectric it's returning all the objects that match the dates in `salesDates`, however if there's a date in `salesDates` but not in `jsonSalesData`, i need the object returned with the date not matched and a sales of 0. For example if '2021/06/29' exists in `salesDates` but does not exist in the jsonSalesData, i need to return the object with a sales of 0 -- {date: '2021/06/29', company: 'ABC', sales: 0}